# Append method making invalid list

Tags: python, append

I have an application where i read content from a json file, do some formatting and pass the list for another class.

When i print the first item i see this:

```
['.docx', '.ppt']
```

And the second is

```
['.py', '.java', '.cpp']
```

I append them to a list, but when i print the list this is the result:

```
[['.docx', '.ppt'], "['.py', '.java', '.cpp']"]
```

As this is an invalid list, i cant use for my methods who require a list as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). `append()` adds the list (as a single reference) to the first list. `extend()` will add its contents:

```
a = ['.docx', '.ppt']
b = ['.py', '.java', '.cpp']
a.extend(b)
a
# ['.docx', '.ppt', '.py', '.java', '.cpp']
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is using extract like :

```
aList = ['.docx', '.ppt']
blist =['.py', '.java', '.cpp']

aList.extend(blist)
print (aList)
```

Second one is just using `+` means :

```
aList = ['.docx', '.ppt']
blist =['.py', '.java', '.cpp']

aList= aList + blist
print (aList)
```

Both output :

```
['.docx', '.ppt', '.py', '.java', '.cpp']
```

> Using extract is more professional